# How to deploy jar of maven application on a specific server after Jenkins build?

Tags: maven, jenkins, jar, jenkins-plugins, continuous-deployment

I am running my maven application on Jenkins. when the build is complete, I get the jar file on my machine.
I want to deploy this jar on 2 different servers with specific IP (x.x.x.x) for testing purposes after the build is complete.

What plugins and/or steps should I follow to achieve that ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "deploy"? Copy to that server?

Comment: copy and run on the server

Comment: Do you have an idea about how to copy it to that server ?